# Error when trying to make 4d array in C++ (using std::vector and Eigen matrices)

Tags: c++, arrays, vector

I am trying to make a 4d array as follows:

First I make a function to create a 3d array, initialised so all the elements are zero (which works fine):

```
std::vector<Eigen::Matrix<double, -1, -1 > > vec_of_mats_test(int n_rows,
                                                              int n_cols,
                                                              int n_mats) {


  std::vector<Eigen::Matrix<double, -1, -1 > > my_vec(n_mats);
  Eigen::Matrix<double, -1, -1 > mat_sizes(n_rows, n_cols);

  
  for (int c = 0; c < n_mats; c++) {
    my_vec[c] = mat_sizes;
    for (int i = 0; i < n_rows; i++) {
      for (int j = 0; j < n_cols; j++) {
         my_vec[c](i,j) = 0;
      }
    }
  }


  return(my_vec);

}
```

Then, I have the following function which calls the function above to make a 4d array:

```
 std::vector<std::vector<Eigen::Matrix<double, -1, -1 > > >  4d_array(         int n_rows,
                                                                               int n_cols,
                                                                               int n_mats,
                                                                               int n_vecs) {
   

   std::vector<std::vector<Eigen::Matrix<double, -1, -1 > > > my_4d_array(n_vecs);
   
   for (int c = 0; c < n_vecs; c++) {

     my_4d_array[c] = vec_of_mats_test(n_rows, n_cols, n_mats);
     
   }
   
   
   return(my_4d_array);
   
}
```

However , during compilation I get the following error:

"expected unqualified-id before numeric constant"

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: should be closed as typo: https://godbolt.org/z/7GxbvEaM1 (symbols names can't start with digit).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`4d_array` is not a valid identifier name in C++ because you cannot use a number as the first character of an identifier.

Use another valid name instead.